# Only show items owned by the currently logged in user in category list view

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'd like to be able to provide a "Category List" view that only shows Articles that the currently logged in user owns.

Is there somewhere I can edit the query used to populate the Category List view or an extension that provides this functionality.

Thank you for any help you can provide. -J.

Thank you for your answer. I've written the plugin. Instead of passing in an array of Articles the onContentBeforeDisplay function is called for every article and an ArrayObject of the single article gets passed in. I've been able to identify the articles I want not to be displayed but still cannot get them not to display.

The $params variable has values such as "list_show_xxx" but I can't seem to change or access them.

here is a var_dump($params):

```
object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)#190 (1) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#250 (83) { ["article_layout"]=> string(9) "_:default" ["show_title"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_titles"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_intro"]=> string(1) "1" ["info_block_position"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_category"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_category"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_parent_category"]=> string(1) "0" ["link_parent_category"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["link_author"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_create_date"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_modify_date"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_publish_date"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_item_navigation"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_vote"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_readmore"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_readmore_title"]=> string(1) "1" ["readmore_limit"]=> string(3) "100" ["show_tags"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_icons"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_print_icon"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_email_icon"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_hits"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_noauth"]=> string(1) "0" ["urls_position"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_publishing_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_article_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["save_history"]=> string(1) "1" ["history_limit"]=> int(10) ["show_urls_images_frontend"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_urls_images_backend"]=> string(1) "1" ["targeta"]=> int(0) ["targetb"]=> int(0) ["targetc"]=> int(0) ["float_intro"]=> string(4) "left" ["float_fulltext"]=> string(4) "left" ["category_layout"]=> string(9) "_:default" ["show_category_heading_title_text"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_category_title"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_description"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_description_image"]=> string(1) "0" ["maxLevel"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_empty_categories"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_no_articles"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_subcat_desc"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_cat_num_articles"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_base_description"]=> string(1) "1" ["maxLevelcat"]=> string(2) "-1" ["show_empty_categories_cat"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_subcat_desc_cat"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_cat_num_articles_cat"]=> string(1) "1" ["num_leading_articles"]=> string(1) "1" ["num_intro_articles"]=> string(1) "4" ["num_columns"]=> string(1) "1" ["num_links"]=> string(1) "4" ["multi_column_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_subcategory_content"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_pagination_limit"]=> string(1) "1" ["filter_field"]=> string(5) "title" ["show_headings"]=> string(1) "1" ["list_show_date"]=> string(1) "0" ["date_format"]=> string(0) "" ["list_show_hits"]=> string(1) "1" ["list_show_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["orderby_pri"]=> string(5) "order" ["orderby_sec"]=> string(5) "rdate" ["order_date"]=> string(9) "published" ["show_pagination"]=> string(1) "2" ["show_pagination_results"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_feed_link"]=> string(1) "1" ["feed_summary"]=> string(1) "0" ["feed_show_readmore"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_num"]=> string(2) "10" ["menu_text"]=> int(1) ["show_page_heading"]=> int(0) ["secure"]=> int(0) ["page_title"]=> string(16) "Non-K2 News List" ["page_description"]=> string(33) "BBIC" ["page_rights"]=> NULL ["robots"]=> NULL ["access-edit"]=> bool(true) ["access-view"]=> bool(true) } }
```

I've tried $params->data->list_show_author = "0" but then the page doesn't load, problem is accessing and changing the variables in $param.

So the last step is to figure out how not to show the article. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentBeforeDisplay

You need to write a plugin. Use that event trigger `onContentBeforeDisplay`
With the `$context` variable you can check what is actually displayed so you can find out if its the Category List view. If it is, you can do some manipulating.

The `$article` variable contains the articles which are being rendered. You will need to look into the `$params` variable and check if the user-id of the article belongs to the user. The user-id of the current user can be accessed like so: `JFactory::getUser()->id`

Unset any article which doesn't belong to the user (you will probably have to loop through as the articles are probably stored in an array).

Pro tip: Start of by using `var_dump` on all the arguments that are passed to `onContentBeforeDisplay`